# class template cpp, hpp, cpp

Tags: c++, class, templates, matrix

I have this class in my .hpp file

```
template<class T = int>
class Matrix
{
    public:
    Matrix();
}
```

and I have this Matrix.cpp file

```
#include "Matrix.hpp"
template<class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix()
{
    vector<T> vecN(1, 0);
    _matrix.resize(1, vecN);
    _rows = 1;
    _cols = 1;
}
```

but it won't work, when adding a main

```
#include "Matrix.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Matrix<int> test();
    return 0;
}
```

i get a very weird error saying

`main.cpp:19: undefined reference to Matrix<int>::Matrix(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
main.cpp:19:(.text+0x2d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol Matrix<int>::Matrix(unsigned int, unsigned int)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template code must be in the header, unless it is for specialisations.

This is because the template is used to generate the actual class when you use it.

Comment: what does specialisations mean?

Comment: @Mumfordwiz If you have a template class `A<T>`, you can additionally write a separate eg. `A<float>` with different code, then for float the second class will be used, and for everything else the first.

Comment: @deviantfan got it. Thanks!